# My website getting HTTP ERROR 500 Php

Tags: php

I have update the **Godaddy Php version 5.4 to 7.1** then my working website show error like **HTTP ERROR 500**. How to solve the problem plz help.

Comment: look at your error_log

Comment: I'm going to guess the error is on line 23. Anyone else want to play the error log lottery?

Answer (score 0):

Check in .htaccess file because something wrong in this file or not enable some Apache modules.

Comment: this for php version problem